# Spring boot starter and redis cluster issue

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I deployed a redis cluster using the bitnami/redis-cluster chart. I also set a password `TEST`. This created a service `redis-cluster` which maps to all the nodes

```
kubectl get service
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)             
redis-cluster            ClusterIP      XXX             <none>         6379:30003/TCP 
redis-cluster-headless   ClusterIP      None            <none>         6379/TCP,16379/TCP 
redis-cluster-metrics    ClusterIP      XXX             <none>         9121/TCP
```

I set up a port forward for the service `redis-cluster` on localhost and did a test with redis-cli, and verified I was able to connect with the password `TEST`

I have a spring boot app using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`. Here is the properties

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=localhost:6379
spring.redis.cluster.password=TEST
```

I'm getting such error `noauth hello must be called with the client already authenticated, otherwise the hello <proto> auth <user> <pass> option can be used to authenticate the client and select the resp protocol version at the same time`. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: Nope, I'm using redis sentinel for now